# Convert Edge Detection to Mask

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, metal, edge-detection

Giving an image that I applied an edge detection filter, what would be the way (hopefully efficient/performant one) to achieve a mask of the "sum" of the point in a marked segment?

Image for illustration:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Added example of a lighter image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGgLg.jpg).
As you'll see in the below image, we assume that when the user marks a region (ROI), there will be an object that will "stand out" from its background. Our end goal is to get the most accurate "mask" of this object, so we can use it for ML processing.

[image]

Comment: One suggestion would be to threshold your original image and crop that region. Use morphology to fill regions and clean up any outliers. Then get the contour and and draw the contour filled as white on a black background

Comment: @fmw42 Hey Fred, thank you for replying. I did something similar, it's working for high contrast edge detection. What do you recommend for a scenario where there are far lighter edges? Also, do you do paid consultants by chance?

Comment: @RoiMulia I think you should add an example image that ROI contains lighter edges.

Comment: I agree with `@Burak`. Please post an example with which you are having difficulty.

Comment: What do you call the "sum" ?

Comment: Please see an updated question with the relevant scenario @fmw42

Comment: Please see an updated question with the relevant scenario @Burak

Comment: @YvesDaoust Updated the question, please see the most-bottom image in my update, the "sum" in my perspective is the area between all the relevant edges that generate the mask (in our example, the newspaper).

Comment: Well, there is an area function for contours.

Comment: @YvesDaoust interesting. But how can we get the relevant area only from the paper edges (that will be resulted in the newspapers mask)

Comment: How did you select this mask ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Manually with photoshop, just for the example

Comment: How can an algorithm read your mind ? You need to give objective criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217391/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: It is hard to distinguish object like in the example. So far, the best method I know is [active contours without edges](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23445-chan-vese-active-contours-without-edges). The function requires an initial mask. You may try to give the green rectangle (relevant ROI) as input.

Comment: I suggested "without edges" method, but it may be the case that "snakes" method could work better. I am interested in the results, so please let us know the updates and I will be following.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe we can give you a few tips to improve a "working" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
Given the "ROI" supervision you have, I strongly recommend you to explore GrabCut (as proposed by [YoniChechnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810247/1714410)):
Rother C, Kolmogorov V, Blake A. ["GrabCut" interactive foreground extraction using iterated graph cuts](https://cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/cvl/2012/grabcut-siggraph04.pdf). ACM transactions on graphics (TOG). 2004.

To get a feeling of how this works, you can use power-point's "background removal" tool:
[image]
which is based on GrabCut algorithm.

This is how it looks in power point:
[image]

GrabCut segment the foreground object in a selected ROI mainly based on its foreground/background color distributions, and less on edge/boundary information though this extra information can be integrated into the formulation.

It seems like opencv has a basic implementation of GrabCut, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html).

---

**2.**
If you are seeking a method that uses only the boundary information, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510366/1714410) useful.

---

**3.**
An alternative method is to use NCuts:
Shi J, Malik J. [Normalized cuts and image segmentation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Emalik/papers/SM-ncut.pdf). IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence. 2000.

If you have very reliable edge map, you can modify the "affinity matrix" NCuts works with to be a binary matrix

```
         0  if there is a boundary between i and j
w_ij =   1  if there is no boundary between i and j
         0  if i and j are not neighbors of each other
```

NCuts can be viewed as a way to estimate "robust connected components".

Comment: Thank you for Responding, Shai. GrabCut gives good results, but unfortunately not with the accuracy we need for the inpainting process. I'll give NCuts try as well, I'm giving you the bounty as I feel this answer maxes my CV options before moving to DL methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the two examples you've uploaded I can assume you are thresholding based on difference in color/intensity- I can suggest [grabcut](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) as basic foreground separation- use the edges in the mask in that ROI as input to the algorithm.
Even better- if your thresholding is good as the first image, just skip the edge detection part and this will be the input to grabcut.

======= EDIT =======

@RoiMulia if you need production level I can suggest that you leave the threshold + edge detection direction completly and try background removal techniques (SOTA are currently neural networks such as [Background Matting: The World is Your Green Screen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00626.pdf) ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JE-7OcNrPao))).

You can also try some ready made background removal APIs such as https://www.remove.bg/ or https://clippingmagic.com/

Comment: I did a quick and dirty try out for this, the results are better but still not in the production-level-range. Results: https://imgur.com/a/MgfjH1z . Do we have a way to optimize it?